# Writing microdata programmatically (C# / ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, microdata

Is it possible to write 'value-less' attributes to `WebControl` types?

i.e. going from

1 = `var div = new WebControl(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);`

2 = ???

3 = Rendered output: `<div itemscope></div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can created control (E.g. SomeMicroDataWebControl) derived from WebControl and overrride method "Render". In "Render" you define how your control will look like on page. Then add this class to a page or another control.

Comment: Slightly better:


`public class MicrodataControl : WebControl
{
    public MicrodataControl(string tag) : base(tag) { };
}` as WebControl has a protected property 'tag' so you must derive first.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC take a look at my blog post:

[ASP.NET MVC: Add HTML5 Microdata to your applications using Metadata Providers](http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/asp-net-mvc-add-html5-microdata-to-your-applications-using-metadata-providers/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl control and set anything you like within it. 
W3C though recommends setting a data or role attributes, so you'd have `<div role-scope='item'></div>`